# Add normal distribution line to plot_histogram()

Tags: r, plot, histogram, normal-distribution

I plottet all my data with `plot_histogram()` to a facet grid, where each column(=each factor I am considering in my study) is shown in one plot.

X-axis is the value itself, Y axis is the frequency how the value is distributed amongst the dataset.

Of course in most cases I can see more or less if there is a normal distribution or not, but I'd like to show it with a curve, just as if I'd use `hist()`.

Is there a function or package to get those normal distribution lines in all of those plots at once? I'll put an image of one of the grids here, so you see what I mean.

[image]